# GPS start mode query

Tags: gps, tracking

I am using SIM808 GPS/GSM module. I came across Cold start,Warm start and Hot start in GPS Modules while developing code for a GPRS Tracker for car. I know the difference between them.My question is that if I don't use any start mode then what will be the searching procedure of gps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the GPS receiver does a cold start, it's search space has three dimensions:

- test for each satellite to find which ones are actually in view
- Doppler shift
- pseudo random code offset

Any normal GPS module implements the search procedure internally.  You wouldn't need to worry about implementing your own search procedure.

Comment: Hello Brother,
I have made a gps tracker.I used cold start for first time gps on and warm start for car engine on.But sometimes I see that we miss gps data for a long time.
Can you help me